# About associativity in 'C'

Tags: c

How can i decide or understand whether any statement or expression has left to right or right to left associativity?

Comment: Please don't post in all caps.  It hurts my eyes

Comment: @JaredPar - fixed by the magic of the interweb www.togglecase.com/convert_to_sentence_case.php

Comment: @Barry, nice link.  Will have to keep that one around.

Comment: Jaimin, stop rolling back to that upper-case version - its distracting.

Comment: @Pavel: While edits are *certainly* in order, I have to say that this is a rule of wide enough applicability that peer pressure is *also* in order. I do, however, prefer Jared's approach to bdonlan's: best to start with a soft touch.

Comment: That would seem to apply only to operators.  Personally, I avoid memorizing the precedence and associativity tables for C and C++, for fear of writing something other people find ambiguous and need to decode.

Comment: I don't think anybody speaks in upper case voice on purpose.. Perhaps his capslock was stuck :)

Comment: in doubt () can be welcome and make reading the expression easier... if used wisely... --- whops, thought s/he was talking about precedence ((per se))... too late, time for bad then;/

Answer (score 4):

=, +=, etc, operators that have '=' in them, is right associated.

All others are left-associated.

Comment: Perhaps I miss something, but I don't know how in any of the unary or ternary operators the associativity is relevant.... Well, I accept your claim anyway,

Answer (score 2):

Here's a [table of C++ operator precedence](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/operator_precedence).

The operator precedence and associativity are the same in C and C++ (modulo operators that don't exist in the former).

Comment: Aren't the precedence and associativity the same (modulo operators that don't exist in C)?

Comment: @Cogwhere: They are, but a user at a level that they need to ask about precedence can't be guaranteed to know that, so the answer should *say* as much or link to a c specific reference. But in any case, bare links are rotten SO answers. At a minimum summarize what's to be found on the other end.

Answer (score 0):

Read the standards

EDITED: I don't have the standards myself, but I've found [this link](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Reference_Tables) supposed to be based on the standard.

Also, quoting Kernighan & Ritchie:

> Arithmetic operators associate left to
>   right.
>
> Expressions connected by && or || are
>   evaluated left to right, and
>   evaluation stops as soon as the truth
>   or falsehood of the result is known.
>   Most C programs rely on these
>   properties.
>
> Operators Associativity
>
> () [] -> . left to right
>
> ! ~ ++ -- + - * (type) sizeof right to left
>
> * / % left to right
>
> + - left to right
>
> << >> left to right
>
> < <= > >= left to right
>
> == != left to right
>
> & left to right
>
> ^ left to right
>
> | left to right
>
> && left to right
>
> || left to right
>
> ?: right to left
>
> = += -= *= /= %= &= ^= |= <<= >>= right to left
>
> , left to right
>
> Unary & +, -, and * have higher precedence than the binary forms.

Comment: @GMan, I don't have the standards myself, so I added the alternative information I hav, it might be useul